# d3.js color range and lighter color range

Tags: colors, d3.js

I would like to have two color ranges, the second one must consist off the same colors, but lighter.

```
rangeLength=10
color = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,rangeLength]).range(['red', 'blue']);
colorLigher= d3.scale.linear().domain([1,rangeLength]).range(['red'.lighter(10), 'blue'.lighter(10)]);
```

Obviously doesn't work, as 'red' is a string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `brighter()` function (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors)):

```
length=10
color = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,length]).range(['red', 'blue']);
colorLighter= d3.scale.linear().domain([1,length])
      .range([d3.rgb('red').brighter(), d3.rgb('blue').brighter()]);
```

Comment: This will work in most cases however because 'red' is r255 g0 b0 it does not work, you will end up with the same scale!